# If Jesus was perfect and also God how did he Become Perfect and Learn Obedience?

Tags: hebrews

If Jesus never sinned and was fully God then how do we understand the scripture that states he 'increased in wisdom', 'became perfect', and 'learned obedience'?

Luke 2: 52

> And Jesus increased in wisdom and in stature[a] and in favor with God
>   and man.

Hebrews 2:10

> For it was fitting that he, for whom and by whom all things exist, in
>   bringing many sons to glory, should make the founder of their
>   salvation perfect through suffering.

Hebrews 5:8-9

> Although he was a son, he learned obedience through what he suffered.
>   And being made perfect, he became the source of eternal salvation to
>   all who obey him,

We see that the same author (in Hebrews) himself says that Jesus is already perfect.

Hebrews 4:15

> For we do not have a high priest who is unable to sympathize with our
>   weaknesses, but one who in every respect has been tempted as we are,
>   yet without sin.

Hebrews 7:26

> For it was indeed fitting that we should have such a high priest,
>   holy, innocent, unstained, separated from sinners, and exalted above
>   the heavens.

Hebrews 9:14

> how much more will the blood of Christ, who through the eternal
>   Spirit offered himself without blemish to God, purify our[a]
>   conscience from dead works to serve the living God.

Comment: See also: [Does “learned obedience” imply that Jesus was disobedient?](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/378/3555) and [What does “made perfect” mean in Heb 5:9?](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/21323/3555)

Comment: This begins with theological assumptions that do not start from the text. Please keep in mind we stick to the text in its original context. If you are looking for a Christian interpretation, I suggest [Christianity.SE]. Neither of these texts appear to begin with a presumption of Jesus' perfection nor Godhood, whereas your question does.